# passing variable to view ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables

I have 2 views, one to return all the locations belonging to a project, the other returns a json file containing the locations that used to show them on a google map.
Listing the locations works like this as the id is sent with the actionlink, but how do I send the project ID to the Map view?

```
public ActionResult GoogleMaps(int id)
  {
      return View(Project.Find(id).DeviceLocations);
  }


  //[AutoRefresh(DurationInSeconds = 30)]

  public ActionResult Map(int id)
  {
      var map = Project.Find(id).DeviceLocations;
      Locations l = new Locations();
      l.locations = map;
      return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people construct a model (class) specifically to handle all of the values being passed from the controller. So, your model would have a property called DeviceID, and would thus be strongly typed.

Alternately, you can use ViewData:

You can put this in your controller:

```
ViewData["DeviceID"] = id;
```

Then, in your view, you will need to cast it before you use it, like this:

```
(int)ViewData["DeviceID"]
```

Comment: but using ViewData is bad practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Include a get, set property "project ID" in your Locations class.